# Is it possible to customize access modifiers behaviour?

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

I have a winform application made up of two assemblies : a business layer and a front-end layer. Each usercontrol (front-end layer) relates to a class of the business layer, i.e. *CustomerUserControl* uses the *Customer* class.

Editable properties, i.e. *Customer.Name*,  have public setters so that their values can be modified through front-end controls.

My question is : is it possible to change the setter accessibility of a property to make it more or less restrictive only for specific classes. In my example, the *Customer.Name* setter would be internal, that is not accessible by front-end controls but accessible for its corresponding control *CustomerUserControl*. Or else, the setter would be public but not accessible to controls other than *CustomerUserControl*.

Is it possible to achieve such customized access rights ?

Comment: Have you considered immutable or freeze-able structures?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". We use tags for that here on [so].

Comment: @asawyer: Are you talking about passing a tuple around?

Comment: @jolySoft I thought maybe an immutable style object would sidestep the problem entirely is all.

Comment: @Anne-Christine: Why don't you accept an answer, Oliver's is the most complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the internal modifier for the setter. This makes it only accessible inside the assembly. If the CustomerUserControl is in another assembly then you can use the InternalsVisibleToAttribute

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("assembly name")]
```

**EDIT**: You are right. Here is another possibility:
Declare an interface that would be implemented by controls that are allowed to set names:

```
public interface ICustomerNameProvider
{
    string CustomerName { get; }
}
```

In Customer add a method:

```
public void SetName(ICustomerNameProvider customerNameProvider)
{
    this.Name = customerNameProvider.CustomerName;
}
```

The CustomerUserControl would call it like this:

```
cust.SetName(this);
```

Of cause this is not absolutely fool proof, but accidentally passing the wrong control would become impossible.

Comment: From the question, there are two assemblies: business and UI, and all the UserControls are in the UI assembly. This would not prevent ProductUserControl from accessing the setter of Customer.Name

Comment: +1, the edited answer is a step up in design quality from what I posted. Just make sure to have the interfaces in a third, separate assembly to avoid circular references.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no way to apply what you're asking for directly to a property setter, since it doesn't know where the call initiated from. However, you could cobble something together using mutator methods:

```
public class Customer
{
   ...
   public string Name
   {
      get;
      private set;
   }

   public void SetName(string callingControlName, string newName)
   {
      // you'd use TypeOf the same way to pass in callingControlName
      if(TypeOf(this).Name + "UserControl" == callingControlName)
         this.Name = newName;
   }
   ...
}
```

Note that this is ridiculously tightly coupled and poor design practice, but it ought to do what you want, provided you strictly adhere to the naming conventions outlined in the question (`Customer` matches 1:1 with `CustomerUserControl`). As an aside, I didn't just statically compare `callingControlName` to `"CustomerUserControl"` in order to gain a slight improvement in maintainability, in case you wanted to do something like rename the CustomerUserControl class. Also important to note is the fact that this is easily defeasible by calling `Customer.SetName("CustomerUserControl","badName")`. Hopefully you aren't exposing this to coders who would do things like that, but it is entirely possible.

The real issue here is that your business layer shouldn't be dependent on your presentation layer. Why would you need to restrict set access to a specific UserControl? If you have a genuine need (and I can't think of one) that a business property's `set` only be accessible from a certain UI class, then some significant redesigning of your application is called for.

Comment: ProductUserControl could still pretend to be a CustomerUserControl. `SetName(new CustomerUserControl(),”newName”)`

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes - Yes, it could, and I explicitly mentioned that in my answer. Did you miss it?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: Sorry, I focussed on the code. See the EDIT of my answer. Here the business layer does not relay on the UI layer. ICustomerNameProvider would either be declared in a business layer assembly or in a contracts assembly.

Answer (score -2):

You can limit the scope of get or set accessors like this:

```
//private set accessor - this is what you're looking for
public int SomeProperty { get; private set; } 

//private get accessor
public int SomeOtherProperty { private get; set; }
```

Comment: How does this stop the value being set by another control?

Comment: Downvoting me because I downvoted you kind of goes against the principles of this site. Did you miss the `private set` part of my answer?

Comment: How do you get the value in there?  What is the purpose of public set SomeOtherProperty?  What is the relation between these two properties?

Comment: The first has a `private set` accessor and the second has a `private get` accessor. It was intended to show that you can control access to both the get and set accessors of a property. I included the `private set` first, because that's what OP was asking for.

Comment: The question is whether the value can be set by one class and one class only.  One to one mapping between UI and business objects.  That's way I down voted you because you didn't answer the question.  Anyway as I say, thanks for your time.

Comment: That's what my answer does. With a `private set` accessor, you can only set the property from inside the class it belongs to. Based on your comments and your answer, it seems like you really need to read up on this stuff a bit more.

Comment: Read the question again.  There are UI objects and Business objects in different assemblies

Comment: jolySoft is right. What I would like is make the setter (which is private or internal) exceptionally accessible for one specific class from another assembly.

Comment: Is the other class in any way related?

Comment: The relation between them is that the business object is the datasource of the usercontrol bindingsource and it's the only control where the object should be editable. There is a one to one mapping between business classes and such controls.